# PHP CURL: The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated

Tags: php

I got this message:

```
Deprecated: curl_setopt_array(): The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class instead
```

**I know** that I may rewrite my code using `CURLFile` class, but it's awailable only from 5.5.

My site **must** run on PHP 5.3, PHP 5.4 or PHP 5.5, so I can't drop 5.3 and 5.4 compatibility. So I  can't use CURLFile.

How can I rewrite code to make it run on any PHP without any PHP version checks?

Comment: Would not be enough to use shutup operator @? `@curl_setopt_array(...);`

Comment: It had a pretty big mouth in my case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best solution I have found is [/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/PostFile.php](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/3a0787217e6c0246b457e637ddd33332efea1d2a/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/PostFile.php#L90):

```
public function getCurlValue()
{
    // PHP 5.5 introduced a CurlFile object that deprecates the old @filename syntax
    // See: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload
    if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
        return curl_file_create($this->filename, $this->contentType, $this->postname);
    }

    // Use the old style if using an older version of PHP
    $value = "@{$this->filename};filename=" . $this->postname;
    if ($this->contentType) {
        $value .= ';type=' . $this->contentType;
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! I need to be PHP 5.4 and 7 Compatible and this seems to be the only thing working in my case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This one is not bad too: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-file-create.php#114538

Answer (score 5):

I believe this will allow you to use the old way without throwing a warning (if simply suppressing via `@` is not acceptable):

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
```

See [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload#backward_compatibility)

Comment: There is no such option: "Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD" http://3v4l.org/caAj8

Comment: I'm afraid then that you may have to detect version detection to your code:

    `if(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION == 5 && PHP_MINOR_VERSION >= 5) { /* CURLFile */ }
    else { /* Old way */ }`

Comment: Upper levels of abstraction shouldn't rely on lower :(

Comment: When using multiple versions, you either accept the changes and ignore deprecated warning, or something like: http://3v4l.org/RfnY7